# Creating a textured object infront of the current character in unity 3d

Tags: unity, c#

I've spent about half a day trying to get my head round this and I'm not having too much luck, essentially what I want to do is play an animation and then once the animation has finished create a flat disk shaped object in front of the current player, the code I have is as follows, please see my comments below for a list of problems:

Note this is cut down code to make the example easy.

```
static int idleState = Animator.StringToHash("Base Layer.idle");
static int portalState = Animator.StringToHash("Base Layer.Portal");

private RenderTexture portal_texture = Resources.Load("Portal") as RenderTexture;

void Start () {
    portal_texture = Resources.Load("Portal") as RenderTexture;
    anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    if(anim.layerCount ==2){
        anim.SetLayerWeight(1, 1);
    }
}

void Update () {

    if(Input.GetKey("p")){
        anim.SetBool("cast_portal", true);
    }

    if(Input.GetKeyUp("p")){
        sphere = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Sphere);
        sphere.transform.position = transform.TransformPoint(Vector3.zero);
        sphere.transform.localScale = new Vector3(3,3,1);
        Vector3 temp = sphere.transform.localScale;
        temp.x = (sphere.transform.localScale.x + 12.0f) * 0.5f;
        sphere.transform.localScale = temp;   
        sphere.renderer.material.mainTexture = portal_texture;    
    }
}
```

Problems

1. The render texture doesn't appear on the object
2. I need to have the object appear about 10 meters infront of where the character is facing, note I'm using a third person controller so camera position won't cut it.
3. How come in the inspector I can set any of the scaling options to 0.001 but if I try it in vector3 it throws an exception when compiling?
4. Where do I need to put this code so it only adds the sphere once the animation has finished?

I only started with unity this week so I'm probably missing something very obvious, I'm just having a bit of a brain freeze so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can utilize prefabs and public fields on a MonoBehaviour to make this a lot easier:

```
public class YourObject : MonoBehaviour {

    // The prefab we want to instantiate when we press p.
    // This needs to be set in the inspector; you'll see a field pop up in
    // the inspector where you can select the prefab to instantiate.
    // Always be sure to make this public so the inspector can see it.
    public GameObject myPrefab;

    void Start() {
        // Animation stuff
    }

    void Update() {

        if (Input.GetKey("p")) {
            // Play the animation
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyUp("p")) {
            // Here we just instantiate our prefab.
            // We can use transform.forward to get the direction our character is facing.
            // In this case, we mulitply it by 10 to create the prefab 10 units away.
            GameObject.Instantiate(myPrefab, transform.forward * 10, Quaternion.identity);
        }
    }
}
```

This makes your code much simpler and you can modify the prefab however you want.

I sadly do not know a whole lot about animation in Unity, so I cannot answer that part of your question. However, something tells me you might want to try using `Animation.Play()` instead of setting some kind of value to play an animation :)

Comment: Thanks for your help matey for extra love How would you go about tranforming forward and up?

Comment: @MrkFldig What exactly do you mean? Spawning the object above you instead of in front (use `transform.up`)? Or moving your character or the spawned prefab?